# how to give Anonymous access to reports

Tags: sql-server, networking, reporting-services

I have window server2008 on which i have remote access.

Using report builder tool we have created a report named PopulationReport.

When i take the remote access using my domain profile and hit the URL

"http://ServerIP/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/New20Folder/PopulationReport&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=Excel"

It provides the report in excel format.

but when hit the url using some other machine it demands the domain Credentials.

How can i make this URL open(or say public) or at least a system on the same network(LAN) can access it.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to ensure trust between the reporting system and the other users who do not belong to your domain. In my case, I made ​​rolle database related to specific audiences or their IP address, works fine.